# Questions regarding margins in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

*emphasized text*[image]

If I keep 16dp as margin all around 4 sides,why 16 dp length or width is different from left and top?

[In the second image,as you can see I have set height as wrap_content and margin is 0 from top too.But still it is applying space from top.So,why it is doing that?What if I add some margin from top?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IfHr.png)

Comment: Did you mean in your image show different distance from let and top? And you already added 16dp margin 4 sides so wh it is not the same 4 sides?

If it is yes. Your image are bounded with  wrap content width and height so it takes default width and height from center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have to set the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `match_constraint` or the special `0dp` value inside the `layout.xml` file. Otherwise looks like you're using `wrap_content` so it's respecting the constraints by adapting the view to its size.

Comment: If the question is: why is it still vertically centered it is because the bottom of the image view it is still constrained to the bottom of the parent. If you remove that constraint it should go to the top with the specified margin.

Comment: But,I havent applied any margin.It is set to zero on both top and bottom.So,why it is applying space then.It should not because margin is set to zero on top and bottom.

Comment: Right. Because there is a top constraint that says: stick to the top (image top to parent top) and there's another one that says stick to the bottom (image bottom to parent bottom) so it "balances" and it stays in the middle. If you want it to stay on top you should remove the bottom constraint that attaches the image view to the parent bottom

Comment: So,that means it ignores margins?Even if I apply any value to top or bottom,it will stay center?

Comment: the margins are calculated and they are there in the view hierarchy but the visual effect that is centered. if you would like to move the image _a little bit up_ you can play with the ConstraintLayout bias. Which is the sliders that initially have a 50 inside them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378079/query-in-image-size-in-android-studio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63374219/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added-logcat-error