# Query in image size in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, imageview, pixel

[image]

Hello. There is a ball image of 640X480.In the image, as you can see I have specified layout_width as 849px and layout_height as 680 px.I have taken a background colour of blue.As layout_width specified is much more than 640px(width size of image), then why the image's left side and right side is not surrounded with blue background.Image's top and bottom is surrounded with blue background.

XML Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="849px"
        android:layout_height="680px"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ball_640x480" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

What I cant understand is in the image,after setting wrap_content also why is still there white space below and above the image?

Below is the updated xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ball_640x480" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the XML code so it's easier to help you debug it

Comment: I have added the XML code.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is given due to the fact that the image is not as big as the `ImageView` is. If you would like the image to completely fill the `View` you could use the property `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`. You can follow along [this visual guide](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide) on ImageView's different scale types and see how it behaves on different scale types.

If you would like to have a border along the `ImageView` I would not use the `android:background` property because your image is going to be drawn on top of the background and probably completely cover it.

My approach would be to have a parent view that is just a little bit bigger than the image view and that view hold the background property. You can easily do that with a `FrameLayout` and applying some `android:layout_margin` to the `ImageView` like the following example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_width="849px"
            android:layout_height="680px"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ball_640x480" />
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Screenshot related to the comments:
[image: Screenshot]

#### Code that works

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ball_640x480"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.Please see the second image and answer my question.

Comment: `wrap_content` will adapt your `ImageView` size to the image size that is loading. If you want your picture to cover the entire `ImageView` use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`. Or maybe what you are looking for is setting the background for the parent view to `android:background="@drawable/ball_640x480"`

Without updated XML there isn't much more I can say

Comment: I have added the updated xml.So,what you are saying is that the white space below and above the image is part of the source image which I loaded?Because if the properties are set to wrap_content,then there shouldnt be white space at all.Correct me if I am wrong.I dont think we need to use android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: By the last setup of your layout you've updated it should make the image view as big as its source and center it; vertically and horizontally. Checkout the screenshot I pasted where I have a similar use-case: It behaves exactly as I describe

Comment: so what you are saying is that in my image you also don't know why white space is coming?

Comment: Without the image at hand I cannot ensure the file is or it isn't the problem and using a configuration like the last one you've posted should be fine.

Comment: so you want me to attach image which I am using?

Comment: That would be helpful

Comment: The image is perfect, it doesn't have any extra background. Check out the last piece of code, works fine for me.