# Activity has leaked window that was originally added logcat error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences, android-room

Please solve my error.I am unable to figure out.

When I click on submit button,my app crashes.Why?Let me know if you want any more input from my side.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    EditText txt1, txt2,txt3;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=findViewById(R.id.button);
        txt1=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        txt2=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextEmailAddress2);
        txt3=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
        SharedPreferences pref     = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean islogged=pref.getBoolean("key3",false);
        if (islogged){
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String                   email     = txt2.getText().toString();
                String                   password = txt3.getText().toString();

                    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                SharedPreferences pref     = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed       = pref.edit();
                ed.putString("key1", email);
                ed.putString("key2", password);
                ed.putBoolean("key3",true);
                ed.apply();


    }
});
    }
}
```

MainActivity2.java

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    EditText txt1, txt2;
    CheckBox keeplog;
    Boolean b=false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        btn=findViewById(R.id.login);
        txt1=findViewById(R.id.loginemail);
        txt2=findViewById(R.id.loginpassword);
        keeplog=findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        keeplog.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                                    b=isChecked;
                                               }
                                           });
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean islogin=pref.getBoolean("key4",false);
        if (islogin){
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity2.this,HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);

                        String email = pref.getString("key1", null);
                        String password = pref.getString("key2", null);
                        String email2 = txt1.getText().toString();
                        String password2 = txt2.getText().toString();
                        SharedPreferences pref2 = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor ed       = pref2.edit();
                        ed.putBoolean("key4",b);

                        ed.apply();


                        if (email.equals(email2) && password.equals(password2)) {

                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, HomeScreen.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }


                    }
                });
```

HomeScreen.java

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity{

    Button button1,button2;
    EditText n;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    String Note;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.id1) {
            final AlertDialog dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

            n = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edt_comment);
             button1 = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
             button2 = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
            dialogBuilder.show();
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialogBuilder.dismiss();
                }
            });
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    SAVETASK();
                   // dialogBuilder.dismiss();
                }
            });



        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.id2) {
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeScreen.this,MainActivity2.class));

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void SAVETASK() {
        Note = n.getText().toString();
       //password = txt2.getText().toString();
        class Savedata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pd = new ProgressDialog(HomeScreen.this);
                pd.setTitle("Saving data");
                pd.setMessage("Please Wailt");
                pd.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                Task task = new Task();
                task.setNote(Note);

                DatabaseClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getAppDatabase().taskdao().insert(task);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                pd.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, MainActivity2.class);
              //  startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        Savedata savedata = new Savedata();
        savedata.execute();
    }


}
```

Task.java

```
@Entity
public class Task implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int    id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String Note;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return Note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        Note = note;
    }
}
```

TaskDao.java

```
@Dao
public interface TaskDao {

    @Query("select * from task")
    List<Task> getalldata();

    @Insert
    void insert(Task task);

    @Update
    void update(Task task);

    @Delete
    void Delete(Task task);
}
```

AppDatabase.java

```
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
        public abstract TaskDao taskdao();
}
```

DatabaseClient.java

```
public class DatabaseClient {
    private Context context;
    private static DatabaseClient mInstance;
    private AppDatabase appDatabase;
    private DatabaseClient(Context mctx)
    {
        this.context=mctx;
        appDatabase= Room.databaseBuilder(mctx,AppDatabase.class,"MYTODO").build();
    }
    public static synchronized DatabaseClient getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(mInstance==null)
        {
            mInstance=new DatabaseClient(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
    public AppDatabase getAppDatabase()
    {
        return appDatabase;
    }
}
```

Logcat error:

```
com.example.sharedprefdemo E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.sharedprefdemo.HomeScreen has leaked window DecorView@d93e50e[Saving data] that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:765)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:429)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:473)
        at com.example.sharedprefdemo.HomeScreen$1Savedata.onPreExecute(HomeScreen.java:95)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:708)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:655)
        at com.example.sharedprefdemo.HomeScreen.SAVETASK(HomeScreen.java:117)
        at com.example.sharedprefdemo.HomeScreen$2.onClick(HomeScreen.java:70)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

So when I click on submit button,my app crashes automatically.I dont know what is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before showing dialog

   if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
   dialog.dismiss();//or cancel()
   }
2. Try moving the dialog and its initialization from asyncthread

   HomeScreen has leaked window DecorView@d93e50e[Saving data] that was originally added here
   [answer to this error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2850597/7540461)

Comment: sorry brother I didnt get what you said.